# How can I see which version of a package I'm using?

Tags: package

I'm curious to see which version of a package I'm using to see if it is out of date. I don't see a `package-` function that looks applicable.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, the answer to the other question does indeed answer my question. The question ought to be updated to "How can I find which version of a particular package I am using?". i.e. `s/mode/package`.

Answer (score 6):

As you noticed Emacs itself doesn't provide any convenient command for this purpose.  I had the same problem and wrote a little package called [pkg-info](https://github.com/lunaryorn/pkg-info.el) to address this issue.

Install it from MELPA with `M-x package-install RET pkg-info` and then type `M-x pkg-info-package-version RET magit` to see the version of the `magit` package.

Comment: As of Emacs 26.3 (on macOS 10.14), `pkg-info-package-version` is no longer available.

Comment: @miguelmorin It never was; pkg-info is a separate package.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `M-x list-packages` to view list of available and installed packages with versions.  And you could mark packages for update with `U`, then use `x` to eXecute the updating.  And `M-x package-list-packages` is an alias for `list-packages`.

More: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Menu.html